# How many free ultrafilters on $\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: set-theory

Is it known if the following question has any answer (possibly under some certain set of axioms) :

How many free ultrafilters there are on $\mathbb{N}$ ?

I am aware that assuming AC, there is at least one.

Thanks. Any reference is highly appreciated :)

Comment: There are $2^{(2^{|X|})}$ ultrafilters on a set $X$. And there are $|X|$ principal ultrafilters so there are $2^{(2^{|X|})} = P(\mathbb R)$ principal ultrafilters on $\mathbb N$.

Comment: @N.H.: If $X$ is finite, there are only $|X|$ ultrafilters.

Comment: Sure, I should have precised that $X$ was infinite.

Comment: @N.H.: Even when $X$ is infinite, how do you know there are $2^{2^{|X|}}$ different ultrafilters? This doesn't seem obvious to me, even assuming AC.

Comment: This is proven page 133 in _Counterexample in Topology_. The proof was not super obvious if I remember well (I read it long time ago but remembered the result).

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83526/the-set-of-ultrafilters-on-an-infinite-set

Comment: Also, without AC, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/779755/unique-ultrafilter-on-omega